# Git push fails when trying to push a commit containing binary files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a new repo which contains some small binary simulink files (.slx)

I know it's not great to use git with binary files but I don't really have a choice.

When I try and push a commit (to master on BitBucket) containing the binary I get the following

```
$ git push origin master
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:myteamname/projectname.git
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 257.08 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Connection reset by 104.192.143.2
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am able to commit other text files etc with no issue.

I found a page on bitbucket support that mentions issues with large files and suggests increasing the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo, for example:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

but this has no effect for me. Also seems odd as my largest file is only 202kb!

Comment: Your URL `git@bitbucket.org:...` tells Git to use SSH rather than HTTP anyway, so it's definitely not an HTTP buffer size. It's not at all clear to me why the Git at bitbucket is hanging up on your Git.

Comment: good point, I didn't spot that. I might try swapping to using HTTP on this occasion and see if that works